# Picture is not changing when clicked on a different button/radio

Tags: html, css

It looks like this: https://gyazo.com/c56735687c7be879ddc2d544e1cd921d

I'm trying to change the picture whenever a different button/radio is clicked, but so far it has not been working. Ive been told that this can solely be done by css/html, so I tried to followed it but It failed.

This is my code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4keh0uos/1/

```
<div class = "fb featured_box1">
                <input type = "radio"  class = "radiobox" id = "slider1" name ="fpslider"        checked>
                <input type = "radio"  class = "radiobox" id = "slider2" name ="fpslider" >
                <input type = "radio"  class = "radiobox" id = "slider3" name ="fpslider">
                <input type = "radio"  class = "radiobox" id = "slider4" name ="fpslider">

            <div class = "picsliders">
                <div id = "picslider1">
                    <a href = "#"><img src = "arsz_goblin.jpg" alt = ""/></a>
                </div>
                <div id = "picslider2">
                    <a href = "#"><img src = "arsz_hearthstone-wallpaper.jpg" alt = ""/> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.radiobox{
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -49.5px;
z-index: 55;
}
#slider1{
    /*Inherit from radio box, so there is nothing to write */
}

#slider2{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 52%;
}
```

Any ideas where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to make the default state of a slide `opacity: 0`, although I would recommend using `display: none` and `display: block`.

Updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fadil/6jnnq1fp/